# VSTO Outlook Plugin - How to identify if meeting/appoinment in my calendar is through .ics file or received an invite

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I get three types of .ics files generally when do registration for training / conferences.

1. Appointment
2. Meeting without any participant (Just see organizer's name after saving it to my calendar)
3. Meeting with other participants details (rare case but I can save such invite to my calendar).

Apart from these .ics files we do receive direct meeting invites which gets directly added to  the calendar folder.

**My question is how can I identify if particular appointment / meeting saved in my calendar folder is something I received as an invite or I saved it through .ics file.**

**Is there any MAPI property / any other property/option through which I can confirm this thing ?**

Thanks,
Manoj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `AppointmentItem.GlobalAppointmentID` property - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.globalappointmentid

Keep in mind that `AppointmentItem.GlobalAppointmentID` may or may not match what you have in the `UID` attribute in an ICS file - generally, it is embedded inside. You can see it in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) if you click IMessage button and select the GlobalObjectId property:
[image]

Comment: thanks, I am getting globalappointmentId properly. question is how can we confirm this saved appointment / meeting is from .ics ? Please note after saving it to outlook calendar, user may delete that completely so there is no access of .ics file.

Comment: There is nothing linking an Outlook appointment and an ICS file (or any other source) besides GlobalAppointmentID / UID.

Comment: Dmitry, Ok, does that mean from Globalappointmentid/UID only somehow we can figure out that this particular item is saved through ics or that's not possible ?

Comment: No, `GlobalAppointmentid` only gives you the `UID` that you can match against the one in an ICS file. There is nothing else in the appointment that can tell you anything (filename etc.) where the appointment came from - take a look at the appointment in OutlookSpy (click IMessage) to see if you can spot anything: that is all Outlook has.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, was thinking about a workaround something like to capture attachment open event and then if attachment name is .ics then try to save some header with that particular Appointment item being saved so later that can help in identifying. Not sure about feasibility but will give it a try. Any thoughts on this or any better workaround ?

Comment: But you won't know what the new appointment is - ICS file is first saved to the file system, and then opened (maybe hours later).

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, got your point. It can be done multiple ways so this can't help actually. So there is no workaround for this then. Thanks Again!